# Erro ao dar um select em duas tabelas

Tags: mysql

Estou tentando fazer um select nessas duas tabelas, mas esta trazendo dados errados, eu quero fazer o seguinte, listar as solicitações de empréstimo que ainda não foram alugadas, ou seja, se o `codigo_socio` estivar dentro da tabela emprestados ela fica sem mostrar para o usuário e liste o restante de solicitções que nao estajam na tabela emprestados e sim na `solicitaçãoemprestimo`.

```
EMPRESTADOS
codemprestados
dataemprestimo
horaemprestimo
solicitacaoemprestimo_socio_codigo



SOLICITACAOEMPRESTIMO
codemprestimo
dataemprestimo
horaemprestimo
socio_codigo
```

Estou tentando fazer assim:

```
select se.* from solicitacaoemprestimo se
left join emprestados e on e.solicitacaoemprestimo_socio_codigo = se.socio_codigo
where e.solicitacaoemprestimo_socio_codigo = '41';
```

Mas esta trazendo campo que esta dentro do emprestados, eu queria que não trouxesse o item e sim que filtrasse o que já esta na tabela emprestados. Desde já eu agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

Seria isso?

```
select se.* from solicitacaoemprestimo se
left join emprestados e on e.solicitacaoemprestimo_socio_codigo = se.codemprestimo
where e.codemprestados is null AND se.socio_codigo = '41'
/* retorna apenas o que existe na tabela solicitacaoemprestimo e não na emprestados e que o socio_codigo seja igual a 41 */
```

Comment: Assim, digamos que na solicitação de empréstimo eu tenha três pedidos, aí eu mandei um para a tabela emprestados, quando eu listar eu quero que apareça só os itens que não estejam dentro da tabela emprestados, como eu emprestei teria que aparecer apenas dois itens.

Comment: Nesse exemplo eu tentei e ele não traz nada.

Comment: @CarlosLeandroFerreiradeAlm Alterei aqui novamente. A coluna `codemprestimo` é a mesma da `codemprestados` do Emprestados?

Comment: Atualizei o SELECT com essa coluna.

Comment: Não, não é, mas eu preciso trazer pelo código do sócio, pelo codemprestimo eu consegui também.

Comment: @CarlosLeandroFerreiradeAlm Para isso não é só fazer `where e.codemprestados is null AND se.socio_codigo = '41'` ?

Comment: então, assim: select se.* from solicitacaoemprestimo se
left join emprestados e on e.codemprestados = se.codemprestimo
where e.codemprestados is null AND se.socio_codigo = '41' ; ele traz o que esta dentro do emprestado eu preciso que ele traga os que não forma emprestados.

Comment: A partir do momento que você faz `e.codemprestados is null` ele só vai trazer o que não tiver na tabela emprestados, se está trazendo errado pode ser dados incorretos na tabela. Coloque um exemplo no SqlFiddle pra gente verificar

Comment: o que é um sqlFiddle?

Comment: @CarlosLeandroFerreiradeAlm http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: No lado esquerdo você coloca os create table e inserts (faça alguns inserts que existe no seu banco) e no lado direito vai o select

Comment: eu já fiz isso e ele traz só o que esta dentro da tabela emprestados.

Comment: então, mudei um parâmetro e deu certo. Ficou assim: select se.* from solicitacaoemprestimo se
left join emprestados e on e.solicitacaoemprestimo_codemprestimo = se.codemprestimo
where e.codemprestados is null AND se.socio_codigo = '41';

Comment: mudou essa parte do código: on e.solicitacaoemprestimo_codemprestimo = se.codemprestimo

Comment: Valeu Maicon, obrigado!

Comment: Verdade, não tinha reparado nisso, que bom que deu certo :)

Comment: @CarlosLeandroFerreiradeAlm Atualizei minha resposta com o erro que você achou.

Answer (score 0):

Olha está meio confuso, você não quer que o banco liste quando o código_sócio estiver preenchido pelo que entendi, então seria assim:

```
select se.* from solicitacaoemprestimo se LEFT JOIN emprestados e on
e.solicitacaoemprestimo_socio_codigo = se.socio_codigo where
e.solicitacaoemprestimo_socio_codigo = '';
```

Mas pensando bem isso não funciona, eu penso que o correto seria você criar a chave `codemprestimo` dentro da tabela `Emprestados` e a partir daí listar todas `SOLICITACAOEMPRESTIMO` que não contenham o `codigo_socio`

> Exemplo:

```
select se.* from solicitacaoemprestimo se LEFT JOIN emprestados e on
e.codTabelaEmprestimo = se.codemprestimo where
e.solicitacaoemprestimo_socio_codigo = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi direito o que você esta precisando, tente acrescentar NOT IN na query.

```
SELECT * FROM solicitacaoemprestimo
WHERE socio_codigo = '41'
AND socio_codigo NOT IN (
SELECT solicitacaoemprestimo_socio_codigo FROM emprestador WHERE solicitacaoemprestimo_socio_codigo = '41'
);
```